# changing font colour when a condition is met

Tags: javascript, html, text, colors

does anyone know how I would do this within an HTML-5 web based application? ie I need to change the font colour of a name when a button is pressed. It's for an application that easily shows when players are on or off court in a tennis tournament. so far I have an excel document of all the players loaded in to an html, this is one of the names for instance:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Iapdp.png]

and buttons as follows:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/kEGYm.png]

so I assume I could write an if condition that states if that button is on, then the player's name goes red or something.. I'm also struggling with layout, considering the names are in a table, the button just stays above the table wherever I put it. Any help is much appreciated, Louis.

Comment: What you are looking for is `element.style.color = '#0F0'` except substituting whatever colour you want to use.

Comment: Also how do you know which players name color you want to change if there is only one button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply add/remove a `class` instead of only changing the value.
This class can be referenced via CSS.

**Example**

```
.online_text {
    color: #00ff00;
}
.offline_text {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Your script should add/remove the property so you basically get this *format*:

```
<td ... class="online_text">Oliver Addison</td>
```

Adding the class as example:

```
document.getElementById("onoff").className += "online_text";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the element that you want to change something defining - usually an ID.
For example, `<td id="currentMatch">`

Note that IDs need to remain unique throughout your page.
You can then access it via `document.getElementById("currentMatch")`

To set the color of the text you'd want to use

```
document.getElementById("currentMatch").style.color = "#00FF00"
```

So that's how you change the color.